# Bigcommerce PHP api script ends after certain api calls

Tags: php, api, bigcommerce

I've written a script where i am fetching data from an excel file and on the basis of data creating / updating customers on bigcommerce using api. The problem i am having is that the file size is too large. Although the api rate limit is 20,000 per hour but my script breaks in between 2500 - 3500 api calls. It neither give me an error from api nor a timeout error from browser It just stops.
Here is the code.

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
//print_r($row);continue;
//sleep(2);

$emails = array();
if(isset($row[4]) && $row[4] != '') {
    $emails[] = $row[4];
}
if(isset($row[5]) && $row[5] != '') {
    $emails[] = $row[5];
}
if(isset($row[6]) && $row[6] != '') {
    $emails[] = $row[6];
}
if(isset($row[7]) && $row[7] != '') {
    $emails[] = $row[7];
}
echo count($emails)."<br/>";
if($row[8] == 'Lapsed' || $row[8] == 'Dropped') {
    //echo "Update customer group id to 6";
    for($i=0;$i<count($emails);$i++) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE email='".$emails[$i]."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($Conn_db, $query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $record = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

            if($record['customer_group_id'] != 6) {
                //updating the Customer Group ID Value to “6” for each email
                $api_url = $store_url.'customers/'.$record['customer_id'];

                //$data = array("first_name" => "Andrew");
                $data = array("customer_group_id" => 6);
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url );
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json'));
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0 );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "dev:c8780bee7ad7f80da4664d5d2f189b4f7bf9a64c" );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($data));

                $response = curl_exec( $ch );
                var_dump($response);

                $api_call++;
                echo "API CALL # ".$api_call." <br/>";

                $query = "UPDATE customers SET customer_group_id=6 WHERE customer_id=".$record['customer_id'];
                $result = mysqli_query($Conn_db, $query);

                $log .= "Customer group of customer id ".$record['customer_id']." has been set to 6. <br/>";
            }
        }
    }
    $query = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE notes=".$row[1];
    $result = mysqli_query($Conn_db, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            if($record['custoemr_group_id'] != 6) {
                //updating the Customer Group ID Value to “6” for each email
                $api_url = $store_url.'customers/'.$record['customer_id'];

                //$data = array("first_name" => "Andrew");
                $data = array("customer_group_id" => 6);
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url );
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json'));
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0 );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "dev:c8780bee7ad7f80da4664d5d2f189b4f7bf9a64c" );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($data));

                $response = curl_exec( $ch );
                var_dump($response);

                $api_call++;
                echo "API CALL # ".$api_call." <br/>";

                $query1 = "UPDATE customers SET customer_group_id=6 WHERE customer_id=".$record['customer_id'];
                $result1 = mysqli_query($Conn_db, $query);

                $log .= "Customer group of customer id ".$record['customer_id']." has been set to 6. <br/>";
            }
        }
    }

} else if($row[8] == 'Active') { // if standing = Active
    if($row[9] == 'Joined') {
        for($i=0;$i<count($emails);$i++) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE email='".$emails[$i]."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($Conn_db, $query);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                $record = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

                if($record['customer_group_id'] != 5 || $record['notes'] != $row[1] ) {
                    //updating the Customer Group ID Value to “5” and notes with id for each email
                    $api_url = $store_url.'customers/'.$record['customer_id'];

                    //$data = array("first_name" => "Andrew");
                    $data = array("customer_group_id" => 5, "notes" => $row[1]);
                    $ch = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url );
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json'));
                    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0 );
                    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
                    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
                    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "dev:c8780bee7ad7f80da4664d5d2f189b4f7bf9a64c" );
                    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
                    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($data));

                    $response = curl_exec( $ch );
                    var_dump($response);

                    $api_call++;
                    echo "API CALL # ".$api_call." <br/>";

                    $query = "UPDATE customers SET customer_group_id=5, notes=".$row[1]." WHERE customer_id=".$record['customer_id'];
                    $result = mysqli_query($Conn_db, $query);

                    $log .= "Customer group of customer id ".$record['customer_id']." has been set to 5 and notes updated with ".$row[1].". <br/>";
                }


            } else {
                // CREATE CUSTOMER ON BIGCOMMERCE MAKING API CALL
                $api_url = $store_url.'customers';

                $data = array(
                                "first_name" => $row[2],
                                "last_name"  => $row[3],
                                "email"      => $emails[$i],
                                "customer_group_id" => 6,
                                "notes" => $row[1],
                                "_authentication" => array(
                                                            "password" => $row[1],
                                                            "password_confirmation" => $row[1]
                                                            )
                            );

                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url );
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json'));
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0 );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "dev:c8780bee7ad7f80da4664d5d2f189b4f7bf9a64c" );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($data));

                $response = curl_exec( $ch );
                var_dump($response);

                $api_call++;
                echo "API CALL # ".$api_call." <br/>";

                // FETCH LATEST INSERTED CUSTOMER ON BC AND STORE IN OUR DB
                $api_url = $store_url.'customers?email='.$emails[$i];
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Length: 0') );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0 );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "dev:c8780bee7ad7f80da4664d5d2f189b4f7bf9a64c" );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );

                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );

                $response = curl_exec( $ch );
                var_dump($response);

                $api_call++;
                echo "API CALL # ".$api_call." <br/>";

                $customers = json_decode($response);
                //echo "<pre>";
                //print_r($customers);

                if(!isset($customers[0]->status)) {
                    foreach($customers as $customer) {

                        $query = "INSERT INTO customers (customer_id, company, first_name, last_name, email, phone, date_created, date_modified, store_credit, registration_ip_address, customer_group_id, notes, tax_exempt_category, addresses_url, addresses_resource)
                                    VALUES(".$customer->id.",'".$customer->company."','".$customer->first_name."','".$customer->last_name."','".$customer->email."','".$customer->phone."','".$customer->date_created."','".$customer->date_modified."','".$customer->store_credit."','".$customer->registration_ip_address."','".$customer->customer_group_id."','".$customer->notes."','".$customer->tax_exempt_category."','".$customer->addresses->url."','".$customer->addresses->resource."')";
                        $result = mysqli_query($Conn_db, $query);
                    }
                }

                $log .= "A customer with id ".$customer->id." has been created. <br/>";

            }
        }

        $query = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE notes=".$row[1];
        $result = mysqli_query($Conn_db, $query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                if(in_array($record['email'], $emails)) {
                    continue;
                } else {

                    if($record['customer_group_id'] != 5) {
                        //UPDATE RECORD ON BIGCOMMERCE USING API CALL
                        $api_url = $store_url.'customers/'.$record['customer_id'];

                        //$data = array("first_name" => "Andrew");
                        $data = array("customer_group_id" => 5);
                        $ch = curl_init();
                        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url );
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json'));
                        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0 );
                        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
                        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
                        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "dev:c8780bee7ad7f80da4664d5d2f189b4f7bf9a64c" );
                        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
                        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($data));

                        $response = curl_exec( $ch );
                        var_dump($response);

                        $api_call++;
                        echo "API CALL # ".$api_call." <br/>";

                        $query1 = "UPDATE customers SET customer_group_id=5 WHERE customer_id=".$record['customer_id'];
                        $result1 = mysqli_query($Conn_db, $query);

                        $log .= "Customer group of customer id ".$record['customer_id']." has been set to 5. <br/>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } else if($row[9] == 'Renewal' || $row[9] == 'Rejoined' || $row[9] == 'Upgraded' || $row[9] == 'Downgraded') {
        for($i=0; $i<count($emails);$i++) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE email='".$emails[$i]."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($Conn_db, $query);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                $record = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

                if($record['customer_group_id'] != 5 || $record['notes'] != $row[1]) {
                    //UPDATE RECDORD IN LOCAL DATABASE
                    $q = "UPDATE customers SET notes = ".$row[1].", customer_group_id=5
                            WHERE customer_id=".$record['customer_id'];
                    $r = mysqli_query($Conn_db, $query);

                    //UPDATE RECORD ON BIGCOMMERCE USING API CALL
                    $api_url = $store_url.'customers/'.$record['customer_id'];

                    //$data = array("first_name" => "Andrew");
                    $data = array("customer_group_id" => 5, "notes" => $row[1]);
                    $ch = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url );
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json'));
                    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0 );
                    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
                    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
                    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "dev:c8780bee7ad7f80da4664d5d2f189b4f7bf9a64c" );
                    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
                    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($data));

                    $response = curl_exec( $ch );
                    var_dump($response);

                    $api_call++;
                    echo "API CALL # ".$api_call." <br/>";

                    $log .= "Customer group of customer id ".$record['customer_id']." has been set to 6 and the customer notes has been updated to ".$row[1].". <br/>";
                }

            } else {

                // CREATE CUSTOMER ON BIGCOMMERCE MAKING API CALL
                $api_url = $store_url.'customers';

                //$data = array("first_name" => "Andrew");
                $data = array(
                                "first_name" => $row[2],
                                "last_name"  => $row[3],
                                "email"      => $emails[$i],
                                "customer_group_id" => 6,
                                "notes" => $row[1],
                                "_authentication" => array(
                                                            "password" => $row[1],
                                                            "password_confirmation" => $row[1]
                                                            )
                            );
                //$data = array("customer_group_id" => 5, "notes" => 'test');
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url );
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json'));
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0 );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "dev:c8780bee7ad7f80da4664d5d2f189b4f7bf9a64c" );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($data));

                $response = curl_exec( $ch );
                var_dump($response);

                $api_call++;
                echo "API CALL # ".$api_call." <br/>";

                // FETCH LATEST INSERTED CUSTOMER ON BC AND STORE IN OUR DB
                $api_url = 'https://store-h9bfkoe.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/customers?email='.$emails[$i];
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Length: 0') );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0 );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "dev:c8780bee7ad7f80da4664d5d2f189b4f7bf9a64c" );
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );

                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );

                $response = curl_exec( $ch );
                var_dump($response);

                $api_call++;
                echo "API CALL # ".$api_call." <br/>";

                $customers = json_decode($response);
                //echo "<pre>";
                //print_r($customers);

                if(!isset($customers[0]->status)) {
                    foreach($customers as $customer) {

                        $query = "INSERT INTO customers (customer_id, company, first_name, last_name, email, phone, date_created, date_modified, store_credit, registration_ip_address, customer_group_id, notes, tax_exempt_category, addresses_url, addresses_resource)
                                    VALUES(".$customer->id.",'".$customer->company."','".$customer->first_name."','".$customer->last_name."','".$customer->email."','".$customer->phone."','".$customer->date_created."','".$customer->date_modified."','".$customer->store_credit."','".$customer->registration_ip_address."','".$customer->customer_group_id."','".$customer->notes."','".$customer->tax_exempt_category."','".$customer->addresses->url."','".$customer->addresses->resource."')";
                        $result = mysqli_query($Conn_db, $query);

                        $log .= "A customer with customer id ".$customer->id." has been created. <br/>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Can someone please tell me what could be the possible reason of this anomaly?

Comment: I was working on something similar and never completed it. I had mine create a local MySQL Table when a button was clicked. This way I could do all my changes and stage them, then push them example SyncFromBC & SyncToBC buttons. 

If you need more info let me know its the only idea I had since the API is not really that fast either. I have the code and just really never finished it, If you are interested I can send it to you and you can see if you can come up with a solution. Right now the customers table is having issues syncing but it appears you have taken care of that already.